# How do I join two mongodb collections together using a mongoose controller route?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Sorry, I'm pretty new with node.js and express. I'm trying to setup a mongoose schema that will allow a user to create a character and store that character in the collection associated with that User. I have two schemas, one for user and one for character.

So far, I have tried using `.populate`, I've tried pushing into the user array on my character schema. And it doesn't return the results i'm wanting.

Here are my schema's and my route file that should be setup to create a new user, and a character. But i'm not sure how to attach that newly created character to my user. When I tried some other variations, I was able to get a character ID to save in mongodb under a user but it would overwrite the current characterId already saved in there.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const characterSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    job: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    race: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    level: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,

    },
    user: [{
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]

});

const Character = mongoose.model('Character', characterSchema);
module.exports = Character;
```

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,

    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error" + err))
    });


    router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.id)
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json("error" + err))
    })


router.route('/character').get((req, res) => {
    Character.find()
        .then(characters => res.json(characters))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("error" + err))
})


router.route('/character').post((req, res)=> {
    const newCharacter = new Character({
        name: req.body.name,
        job: req.body.job,
        race: req.body.race,
        level: req.body.level
    })
    newCharacter
    .save()
    .then(character => res.json(character))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("error" + err));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

im not an expert in node.js nor in mongoose, but i have a little bit experiences.

For me it looks weird, because i think you use from user a reference to the character, or do i missunderstood something?
Because a user has a character.

For the handling:
If the User creates an character and post it, you get the user by the cookie, id or whatelse and then update the character.

Something like:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": userID},
    { 
        "$set": {
            "character.$": character
        }
    },
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

So i think this is missing in Usermodel:

```
   character: [{
        type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Character'
    }]
```